# Software to host a GAE app on my own server

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, web-server

I have a Python [Google App Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine) app, and would like to run it on a private server rather than on Google's infrastructure, for cost reasons.

Such apps are designed for GAE, so they can't run on a normal Apache or Tomcat server.
What GAE-compatible server can I use?

Requirements:

- Open source
- About 1000 requests per day, rather stable
- About 10MB of new data per day, rather stable
- Runs on Linux
- Easy to set up and run
- Reliable, minimal maintenance
- Bonus if provided by Ubuntu distribution

High scalability is not a requirement, as there are no traffic peaks.

Comment: What is the language/framework the app is written in?

Comment: @thameera: Python :-)

Comment: What special GAE features does it depend on? I mean, the features that causes the lock-in to GAE.

Comment: Mostly the database I guess: https://github.com/iniju/ankidroid-triage/

Comment: If you don't want to modify the app, you can use [AppScale](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale) to run it unmodified on a private server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku), which satisfies all your requirements.

It is a PaaS software similar to what is used in GAE and Heroku. Once you download Dokku and setup it in your server, you can deploy your app using git pushes. It can host most webframeworks including [Django](https://gun.io/blog/deploying-django-app-on-dokku/) and [Flask](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-dokku-one-click-digitalocean-image-to-deploy-a-python-flask-app).

There are [plugins](https://github.com/progrium/dokku/wiki/Plugins) for almost all major databases.